# create (in batch) a single variable to set data path of mysql

Tags: mysql, batch-file, wamp

I have created a batch variable to the data path of mysql (wamp):

```
set MYSQLDATAPATH="%HOMEDRIVE%\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.21\data"
or
set MYSQLDATAPATH="%HOMEDRIVE%\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.21\data"
```

And it changes according to the version (mysql-wamp and x86/x64):

```
set MYSQLDATAPATH="%HOMEDRIVE%\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.19\data"
or
set MYSQLDATAPATH="%HOMEDRIVE%\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.19\data"
```

etc...

How can I create (in batch) a single variable that set the data path of mysql wamp (MYSQLDATAPATH), regardless of the version (**wampXX** and **mysqlXX**)

Thanks!

Comment: Is it ORIGEN or ORIGIN?

Comment: fixed up. change to MYSQLDATAPATH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "mysqldatapath="
FOR %%a IN (wamp wamp64) DO (
 FOR /f %%d IN ('dir /ad /b "%sourcedir%\%%a\bin\mysql\mysql*" 2^>nul') DO (
  IF exist "%sourcedir%\%%a\bin\mysql\%%d\data" (
   SET "candidate=%sourcedir%\%%a\bin\mysql\%%d"
   CALL :latest %%d
  )
 )
)

ECHO mysqldatapath=%mysqldatapath%

GOTO :EOF

:: latest version required? Format %1 may be mysqlA.C.E or mysqlAB.CD.EF
:latest
IF NOT defined mysqldatapath GOTO newver
:: is newly-detected version in %1 preferred to %sql_ver%?
SET "new_ver=%1"
:: remove "mysql"
SET "new_ver=%new_ver:~5%"
:: replace '.' with ' '
SET "new_ver=%new_ver:.= %"
CALL :vcompare %sql_ver% %new_ver%
:: :vcompare will clear 'new_ver' if new version is preferred
IF NOT DEFINED new_ver GOTO :eof
:newver
SET "mysqldatapath=%candidate%"
SET "sql_ver=%1"
:: remove "mysql"
SET "sql_ver=%sql_ver:~5%"
:: replace '.' with ' '
SET "sql_ver=%sql_ver:.= %"
GOTO :eof

:: version comparison. old old old new new new  as 1 or 2-digit

:vcompare
IF "%4"=="" GOTO :EOF
SET "v_1=0000%1"
SET "v_4=0000%4"
SET /a v_1=1%v_1:~-3%
SET /a v_4=1%v_4:~-3%
IF %v_1%==%v_4% shift&GOTO vcompare
IF %v_1% gtr %v_4% SET "new_ver="
GOTO :eof
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

Not as easy as one may at first expect. The tricky part is in selecting the required version from the candidates.

The first block searches `wamp` and then `wamp64` for a directory named `mysql*` and then nominates a candidate if the `mysql*` directory contains `data`. The `:latest` routine then checks the version numbers and selects the latest to be assigned to `mysqldatapath`.

`:latest` sets `new_ver` to the version number found, eg. 5.7.19 and converts this to `5 7 19`. The `:vcompare` routine then does the mechanics of comparing the three levels, taking care of the potential leading-zero on each level. Note that attempting to compare using literals here will fail, as `5.10.01` would be *less* than `5.9.99` if compared as a literal, but is actually a later (and one would expect, greater) version.

Comment: Thanks for your script. But I do not understand what you mean by "change the setting of sourcedir to suit your circumstances" (What circumstances?... In my question I clarify that the path is %HOMEDRIVE%). Could you give a real example of SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"? Thanks

Comment: `u:\sourcedir` *is* a real example. It's the directory that I use for testing of solutions I post on SO. If you set `sourcedir` to `%HOMEDRIVE%` which suits *your* setup then all should work smoothly. Please note however how I use quotes. This is the accepted way on SO to overcome problems associated with trailing spaces on lines and avoids the gymnastics required combining variables which have quoted values

Comment: Save the entire script in a file say `setmysqlpath.bat` but remove the `setlocal` command. Then in your calling script, simply use the command `call setmysqlpath` - where `setmysqlpath.bat` resides in any directory in your `path`, which you can display by simply typing `path` at the prompt (this is a semicolon-separated list if directories that windows examines in order to find an executable if the executable does not reside in the current directory.)

Comment: To include it within a script, simply copy the entire batch into your script, preferably at the end. Replace the first 2 lines with a label, say :getmysqdir` and ensure that the line before `:getmysqldir` is a `GOTO` or an `exit`. Then within your script body, use `call :getmysqldir` . Observe the colons - they are important. `call :getmysqldir` looks for a routine in *this batch* called `:getmysqldir` whereas `call getmysqldir` (without the colon) searches for an external executable called `getmysqldir` (ie. a program file residing in a directory on the `path`)

Comment: add: I have tested your script for mariadb and it also works. Great job. Thank you